# Reset password on a LANIER 5618 laser printer

Tags: network-printer, password-recovery

I need to reset/recover the administrator password on a LANIER 5618 laser printer. It was probably changed by the former sysadmin and there's no documentation left. Can anybody help me with some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in as supervisor with no password. I would try these combinations before going any further:

- administrator / password
- administrator / administrator
- administrator / blank

All of the above but Admin as username.

Not sure if this will be relevant with your Lanier but to reset on another model:

The system settings in the UP mode can be reset to their defaults. Use the following procedure.

1. Press User Tools/Counter .
2. Hold down the '#' key and then press System Settings.
3. Press yes when the message prompts you to confirm that you want to reset the system settings.
4. Press exit when the message tells you that the settings have been reset.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve got it working with a similar, but not like procedure as you suggested. The reset can be done from the printer console via an option in the service menu or directly from the web interface. On the web interface there’s no username, only a password. I found this default-password by trial and error, as you suggested. It is ‘sysadmin’ (just for the records).

Answer (score 1):

Another default PW for this device is "sysadm" without quotes